# Putting braces indicating lengths in the foreground in a TikZ environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code instructs `TikZ` to draw three lines on the Cartesian plane.  I have a brace under line `j` between the y-axis and the vertical line `\ell_{1}`.  It and its label interfere with the x-axis and `\ell_{1}`. I would like them to be drawn over these lines.  Also, I would like to add a brace under the drawn brace and its label (also in the direction of line `j`) between the y-axis and the vertical line `\ell_{2}`. It should also be in the foreground.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,clip=false,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=15,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=30,
    restrict y to domain=-10:30,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-5:15,blue,name path = A] {0.5*x};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-5:15,blue,name path = B] {2*x};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-10:30,blue,name path = C] (5,x);
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-10:30,blue,name path = D] (9,x);

%These commands label the lines.
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(15,7.5) + ({atan(1/2)}:10pt)$) {$j$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(15,30) + ({atan(2)}:10pt)$) {$k$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(5,-10) + (0pt,-10pt)$) {$\ell_{1}$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(9,-10) + (0pt,-10pt)$) {$\ell_{2}$};


\path[name intersections={of=A and B, by={O}}] node at (O) {};
\path[name intersections={of=A and C, by={Q}}] node at (Q) {};
\path[name intersections={of=A and D, by={R}}] node at (R) {};

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2pt,amplitude=2pt,mirror}] (O)  -- node[below right=3pt and -1pt]{$a$} (Q);
%\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2pt,amplitude=2pt,mirror}] (O)  -- node[above left=3pt and -1pt]{$c$} (R);


\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Alenanno   May you help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change `brace` orientation with `mirror` and position of `brace's middle part` with `aspect`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,clip=false,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=15,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=30,
    restrict y to domain=-10:30,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-5:15,blue,name path = A] {0.5*x};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-5:15,blue,name path = B] {2*x};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-10:30,blue,name path = C] (5,x);
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-10:30,blue,name path = D] (9,x);

%These commands label the lines.
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(15,7.5) + ({atan(1/2)}:10pt)$) {$j$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(15,30) + ({atan(2)}:10pt)$) {$k$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(5,-10) + (0pt,-10pt)$) {$\ell_{1}$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(9,-10) + (0pt,-10pt)$) {$\ell_{2}$};


\path[name intersections={of=A and B, by={O}}] node at (O) {};
\path[name intersections={of=A and C, by={Q}}] node at (Q) {};
\path[name intersections={of=A and D, by={R}}] node at (R) {};

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2pt,amplitude=2pt}] (O)  -- 
    node[above left=2pt and -5pt]{$a$} (Q);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2pt,amplitude=2pt,mirror, aspect=.75}] (O)  -- 
    node[pos=.75, below right=3pt and -3pt]{$c$} (R);


\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd Version: stacked braces**

As the last command you define are for drawing braces, these braces and corresponding labels are already in `foreground`. But if you want that `background` lines don't interfere with labels, `fill` the labels with some background color (probably white) which cover what's behind them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, angles, positioning, intersections, quotes, decorations.markings, backgrounds}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,clip=false,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=15,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=30,
    restrict y to domain=-10:30,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-5:15,blue,name path = A] {0.5*x};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-5:15,blue,name path = B] {2*x};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-10:30,blue,name path = C] (5,x);
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-10:30,blue,name path = D] (9,x);

%These commands label the lines.
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(15,7.5) + ({atan(1/2)}:10pt)$) {$j$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(15,30) + ({atan(2)}:10pt)$) {$k$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(5,-10) + (0pt,-10pt)$) {$\ell_{1}$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(9,-10) + (0pt,-10pt)$) {$\ell_{2}$};

\path[name intersections={of=A and B, by={O}}] node at (O) {};
\path[name intersections={of=A and C, by={Q}}] node at (Q) {};
\path[name intersections={of=A and D, by={R}}] node at (R) {};

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2pt,amplitude=2pt,mirror}] (O)  -- 
    node[below right=2mm and .5mm, fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$a$} (Q);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2pt,amplitude=2pt,mirror}] ([yshift=-5mm]O)  -- 
    node[below right=2mm and .5mm, fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$c$} ([yshift=-5mm]R);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**3rd version: stacked braces with space around them.**

If you don't find a better solution, you can use a `preaction` to draw a white thicker brace before the normal black brace. It looks like a brace with some white space around it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        mybrace/.style={decoration={brace, raise=2pt, amplitude=2pt, mirror}},
        mythickbrace/.style={
            preaction={draw=white, line width=2pt},
            decorate, mybrace}
        ]
\begin{axis}[width=5in,clip=false,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=15,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=30,
    restrict y to domain=-10:30,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-5:15,blue,name path = A] {0.5*x};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-5:15,blue,name path = B] {2*x};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-10:30,blue,name path = C] (5,x);
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-10:30,blue,name path = D] (9,x);

%These commands label the lines.
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(15,7.5) + ({atan(1/2)}:10pt)$) {$j$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(15,30) + ({atan(2)}:10pt)$) {$k$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(5,-10) + (0pt,-10pt)$) {$\ell_{1}$};
\node[font=\footnotesize] at ($(9,-10) + (0pt,-10pt)$) {$\ell_{2}$};


\path[name intersections={of=A and B, by={O}}] node at (O) {};
\path[name intersections={of=A and C, by={Q}}] node at (Q) {};
\path[name intersections={of=A and D, by={R}}] node at (R) {};

\draw[mythickbrace] (O)  -- 
    node[below right=2mm and .5mm, fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$a$} (Q);

\draw[mythickbrace] ([yshift=-5mm]O)  -- 
    node[below right=2mm and .5mm, fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$c$} ([yshift=-5mm]R);


\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want the braces "stacked" - the brace for `c` under the brace for `a`, which is under line `j`.  I see that you used `aspect=.75` so that the typesetting of `c` would not interfere with the drawing of the vertical line `ell_{1}`.  The way that I want to avoid the interference is by putting the pair of braces in the foreground.  Do you know how to make these adjustments?

Comment: @Adelyn: answer updated

Comment: Very nice.  Can the braces be surrounded by white space - to give the appearance of being in the foreground?

Comment: @Adelyn: May be a `preaction` can help. Look at updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that is the display that I wanted!  Thanks.

Comment: I like the thicker brace.  You made the braces `2pt` thick.  Is the default thickness `0.4pt`?

Comment: What is `preaction`?  Is it an option for a node command?

Comment: @Adelyn You'll find it in pages 178 and 179 from pgfmanual.

Comment: The manual states that a `preaction` is an option for a `path` command, `path[draw]` command, and a `node` command.  In the case that it is used in a `\path[draw]` or `\draw` command, the path is drawn using only the options specified by `preaction` and it is drawn again using the other options.  In your code, why does this put some space about the braces?

Comment: @Adelyn This is what happens in this case. First the `brace` is drawn with `preaction` options and later on without them. Replace `white` with some other color and you'll understand it better.

Comment: I missed the `draw=white` option.  I think that answers my question.

Comment: I see from your code that you can have an option of a `yshift` specification within the declarations of coordinate `O` and `R`.  You have `[yshift=-5mm]O` and `[yshift=-5mm]R` to locate ends of the brace directly below the points `O` and `R`.

`\draw[mythickbrace] ([yshift=-5mm]O) -- ([yshift=-5mm]R);`

Do you know how I may find a discussion of this in the manual?

Comment: @Adelyn Page 129. It doesn't say to much there. This syntax if used in several examples in pgfmanual.

Comment: The first time that I have seen this command to do an arithmetic operation in a node via `[yshift=<distance>]O` is in your code.  Can I get the same coordinate via `(O + (0,-5mm))`?

Comment: @Adelyn. With `calc` (from page 141), `($(O)+(0,-5mm)$)` is supposed to do the same. Although it seems to be some problem with the code because it didn't worked to me. I'll try to look at it later.